# What's the difference between $this->container->get('someservice') and $this->get('someservice')?

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection, containers

I am working in a project with several services called inside controllers in this way :

```
$service = $this->get('myservice');
```

but i noticed that i could call 'myservice' in this other way:

```
$service = $this->container->get('myservice');
```

Services of course take advantage of DI
Example of service declaration:

```
myservice:
        public: true
        class: path/to/service
        arguments:
          - '@someEntityRepository'

someEntityRepository:
        class: Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository
        factory: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', getRepository]
        arguments: [path\to\Entity\someEntity]
```

Is there any difference between this calls? If yes, which should i use? Why?

Comment: Since you appear to be just starting out then consider using [action injection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#fetching-services-as-controller-arguments).  Need S3.3+.  Makes the whole question irrelevant.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm working in a project that is in symfony 2.8 and i am not able to upgrade it (although i want it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No difference. Use `$this->get()` when you extend symfony's Controller class. Its shorter to type.

`$this->get('myservice');` is a shortcut for `$this->container->get('myservice');`. And is available in the Controller base class (`Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller`).

Answer (score 0):

Petter was right about the difference between $this-get and $this->container->get(), it is no difference. But you will create a good code if you define Controller as service and inject your services via dependency injections. It adds more flexibility and performance.

Comment: I am currently working in a project in symfony 2.8 and as [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/controller/service.html) says, it is not recommendable. But you are right for newer versions